# Loop through records in PostgreSQL and generate guids?

Tags: database, postgresql, security

I'm in the process of masking my ids from the url. I solved this by having a `GUID` in the URL instead of the primary key (which someone could easily guess). This GUID will map itself to the record just like a primary key.

1. Is this a decent solution? Someone would have to guess the GUID to see other people's data. Is there a security loophole I'm missing here.
2. How could I update my existing database to loop through records using PostgreSQL to update each record with a unique GUID?

Answer (score 5):

You may also create the GUIDs without a Postgres extension, e. g.:

```
ALTER TABLE my_table ADD COLUMN guid UUID 
    DEFAULT MD5(RANDOM()::TEXT || ':' || CURRENT_TIMESTAMP)::UUID NOT NULL;
```

If you need not to define the GUID with a default value, you can use row data for the generation, the primary key for instance:

```
BEGIN;
ALTER TABLE my_table ADD COLUMN guid UUID;
UPDATE my_table SET guid = MD5(id::TEXT || ':' || CURRENT_TIMESTAMP)::UUID;
ALTER TABLE my_table ALTER guid SET NOT NULL;
END;
```

Answer (score 1):

The `uuid-ossp` extension has functions for generating random uuids.

First:

```
create extension "uuid-ossp";
```

then:

```
alter table url add column guid uuid not null default uuid_generate_v4();
```